# What base is ASCII?

Tags: javascript, ascii

I'm trying to make a small JavaScript program where the user inputs a decimal value, and that value is converted to ASCII and given back to the user.

I need to find out what base ASCII is so I can type:
`(User's input).toString(ASCII's base);`

Thank you.

Comment: The question does not make sense. A number is a number, regardless of what base it's expressed in.

Comment: ASCII is just numbers, they don't have a base. Base is only relevant when you convert between numbers and strings, such as parsing input with `parseInt()`.

Comment: You can’t get much higher with the base than 36 anyway, otherwise you’d get a `RangeError`. Maybe you’ll need to use `String.fromCharCode` or `String.fromCodePoint`. It would be helpful if you’d include some example inputs  and expected outputs.

Comment: If the user inputs a decimal value, then it's decimal.

Comment: When a Javascript program gets user input, it's always a string. So `input.toString()` seems redundant.

Comment: Is the user going to input 1000001 and expect that they will get an ASCII character back?  If they are inputting decimal, then it is decimal (base10).

Comment: Is the output you want like this:  If the user enters `65`, then you want to return `A` (the character with an ascii code of 65)?

Comment: @jfriend00, yes that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Are you SUUUURE? Because that is what the radix is for.  Maybe the user is counting in Sixteens (HEX) and when they say 6ixty they don't mean 6 * 10 they mean 6 * 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, under threat of torture, I *had* to state the base of ASCII, it would be 128, simply because there are that many "digits" in the system (each placeholder can hold one of 128 different values, like decimal can hold any one of ten).

However, that's not really going to help you out.

If you want an integral value converted to a string, just use something like:

```
var n = 42;
var n_as_string = n.toString();
```

If you want a string converted to an integer:

```
var back_to_n = parseInt(n_as_string,10);
```

If you're instead talking about the ASCII character given a specific code point, you can use (such as `67` becoming `C`):

```
var c = String.fromCharCode(n);
```

Comment: You should always specify the radix argument to `parseInt`, the default is implementation-dependent.

Comment: I think the OP has ASCII character codes as numbers and wants to convert those to the corresponding ascii character in string form.  Neither `.toString()` nor `parseInt()` will do that by themselves.  I think this question is about `String.fromCharCode()` and `str.charCodeAt()`.

Comment: @jfriend00, from the question: "user inputs a ***decimal*** value".

Comment: I think they want that if the user enters "65", they get back "A".

Comment: @Barmar, that's a good point. Though ES5 specifies radix of 10 (other than for `0x`-type input), not all browsers comply. Hence I've taken on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is defined as being character code 0-127, so 128 chars.

JavaScript uses UTF-16 though so you need to filter the chars.

Answer (score 0):

`toString` with an argument is about converting numbers into a string representation of the number using a different **base**, or **radix**. For intance, you could convert the number 22 into the hex (base 16) representation "16", or the octal (base 8) representation "26", or the binary (base 2) representation "10110".

ASCII is not a numbering system, or a radix, which which you could represent a number, or convert a number into using `toString(radix)`. It's a **character encoding** which maps numbers to characters. There are variations on ASCII but we'll skip over them here. It's a bit confusing because sometimes people use the word "ASCII" to refer the set of characters which it maps, and say things like "an ASCII character", but to be precise ASCII is a character encoding.

I am guessing you want to get **the character whose code is the entered number**, which would be `String.fromCharCode`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode.

Answer (score 0):

You do not understand what the optional parameter for someValue.toString(Radix) does and what it actual does, so lets assume the input is 15, you would have as output

```
val=num.toString(2)  => 1111
val=num.toString(16) => F
val=num.toString()   => 15
```

You need to learn about

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number
```

Comment: Yes I do. I know the bases of octal, ternary, quaternary, hexadecimal, binary, and so on, so forth.